# Texas emulator to test already written programs

Tags: calculator, texas-instruments

I am trying to use TI-Editor as mentioned in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=BIFVVZPyCwY&list=WL) tutorial. I can write a program using this editor on my laptop, but in order to test can I use any emulator or app on my laptop or mobile.

Because as of now I don't have USB wire to the calculator. Which I will get in some period of time, but till then can I check the programs written by me.

I am aware of some emulators but in that I have to write the whole program again manually, is there any laptop emulator in which I can copy past my code and test it.
I am coding the programs as per TI-83 Plus calculator.